# Sphinx alphabetical ordering

Tags: sphinx

I've been banging my head with a problem using Sphinx: I need that the query results are returned in alphabetical order by name.

Simplistically, I have a table with two fields only: 'name' and 'address'.

When I use $sp->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_RELEVANCE) the results come correctly in order of relevance (no alphabetical order instead)

But I need the results orderd by name, so I've tried both:

$sp->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_ATTR_ASC,'name');
and
$sp->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED,'name ASC');

Both with no success.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field 'name' should be declared as attribute:

```
sql_attr_str2ordinal = name
```

You could sort it in alphabetical order using:

```
$sp->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_ATTR_ASC,'name');
```